# How can I get rid of blank spaces in missing values when export to a file 2 dataset with 2 different structures

Tags: file, sas, export, spaces

I'm trying to put in 1 unique file 3 datasets but one of them has different structure, it has 7 columns and the other ones have 5 columns, i tried with MOD option to add to a file that already exist more information with a different structure, i don't have problem with this.

My problem is with the missing values because it has a blank space instead
and if i use proc export I can't add a different layout to the file (i think),
 I'm using `options missing=''`  and doesn't work.

here my example:

Datasets:

```
data bof;
infile datalines dlm='|' dsd;
format f1 f2 f3 f4 f5  $13.;
input f1 f2 f3 f4 f5;
datalines;
BA|Title Example||05282015|
;


data information;
infile datalines dlm='|' dsd;
format name $25. date1 date2 date3 $8. num1 num2 num3 15.;
input name date1 date2 date3 num1 num2 num3;
datalines;
Charles|05062015|04072015||608|272|288
John|05052015|03062015||339|936|760
Esquis|21112015||||340|708
Anna|10052015|08062015||830||984
Donna|15052015|||757|765|
Riana|29012015|27022015||||155
Ron|20122014|18012015||518|667|472
;


data eof;
infile datalines dlm='|' dsd;
format f1 f2 f3 f4 f5  $13.;
input f1 f2 f3 f4 f5;
datalines;
EOF|EOF Example||NO DATE|
;
RUN;
```

My code to generate file:

```
options missing='';
filename arch  "Example.txt"
LRECL= 32767;

data _null_;
set bof;
file arch DLM='|' ;
put f1 f2 f3 f4 f5;


data _null_;
set information;
file arch DLM='|' mod;
put name date1 date2 date3 num1 num2 num3;


data _null_;
set eof;
file arch DLM='|' mod ;
put f1 f2 f3 f4 f5;
run;
```

My result has spaces in missing values

```
BA|Title Example| |05282015| 
Charles|05062015|04072015| |608|272|288
John|05052015|03062015| |339|936|760
Esquis|21112015| | | |340|708
Anna|10052015|08062015| |830| |984
Donna|15052015| | |757|765| 
Riana|29012015|27022015| | | |155
Ron|20122014|18012015| |518|667|472
EOF|EOF Example| |NO DATE|
```

How can I get rid of the blank spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need DSD option on the FILE statement.